# '&' symbol when declaring a variable

Tags: c#, operators

I know this question has been posted all over the internet but I have found some code that declares variables with the ampersand symbol in it and I can't find out what it exactly does.   Would anyone kindly throw me to a website with some info on using this and any other operators when declaring a variable?

```
Rectangle rect1;
Rectangle& local = @rect1;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950616/what-characters-are-allowed-in-c-sharp-class-name wouldn't it be just the same list? With the spec identifiers here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670.aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11067395/what-is-the-ampersand-character-at-the-end-of-an-object-type