# .NET decompiled assembly has an '&' after the type producing build error

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, dotpeek

I have inherited a few assemblies which as far as I know were produced using Visual Studio 2005, .NET Framework 1.1(?), and VB.NET.  Unfortunately, the source code is no longer available to me.  As a result, I have used dotPeek to decompile the assemblies (as C#) and attempt to reverse engineer the projects.  The resulting source code has a few lines that look similar to:

```
// ISSUE: explicit reference operation
// ISSUE: variable of a reference type
string& szDataDescr = @str;
```

The 'string&' is foreign to me (and Visual Studio too apparently).  Visual Studio 2015 is not recognizing this as valid, and I am getting compilation errors.  Is the '&' something that dotPeek has added, or is it some legacy .NET construct that was valid way back then?  Similar comment appears everywhere the 'type&' pattern is used, so I assume it is associated.

Comment: Have you tried other decompilers?

Comment: What does http://ilspy.net/ produce?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11067395/what-is-the-ampersand-character-at-the-end-of-an-object-type on more about the &

Comment: Thanks. That link was beneficial.

Comment: You are using a pretty crappy decompiler, you got what you paid for.   It is formally legal in MSIL, creating a reference to a variable is supported by C++/CLI.  But not in VB.NET or C#, variable references break the abstraction of a property.  If it was actually written in C++/CLI then, well, stop right now and do this the correct way.  Use a telephone next.

Comment: @Hans Passant that's the best thing I have heard all day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The & sign after a type name indicates that it's a reference type, and the @ before a variable name generates a reference to that variable.

If you tried to compile the code, you'll get an error because the compiler treats & as the bitwise and, and will complain that you used a type as if it were a variable. But that's ok because you didn't get it from a C# source file.

Best solution is to use a different decompiler.

- ILSpy: http://ilspy.net/
- .Net Code Reflect: http://www.devextras.com/decompiler/
- .Net Reflector: http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/

Check here for more info on [what the & does in IL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11067395/what-is-the-ampersand-character-at-the-end-of-an-object-type).