# How to refactor this decompiled C# code with invalid reference syntax?

Tags: c#, pass-by-reference, bitwise-operators

After decompiling an assembly, the code it generated resulted in a lot of methods similar to this:

```csharp
internal long m_position;

internal void PutString(long RecordNumber, string s)
{
    if (s == null)
        s = "";
    int byteCount = this.m_Encoding.GetByteCount(s);
    this.SetRecord(RecordNumber);
    this.LengthCheck(byteCount);
    if (byteCount != 0)
        this.m_sw.Write(s);
    // ISSUE: variable of a reference type
    long& local;
    // ISSUE: explicit reference operation
    long num = checked (^(local = ref this.m_position) + (long) byteCount);
    local = num;
}
```

It's only the code starting at `// ISSUE` that's having a problem. As you can see, it contains invalid syntax `long& local;`. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11067654/4028303) which does a great job of explaining what this is. After reading up on C# ref locals, I tried to refactor this method so that it can compile, but I haven't been successful. The `^(local = ref this.m_position)` part really does me in, as I'm not very strong when it comes to bitwise operations.

Could someone help me refactor those last three lines and explain to me how it works? This pattern appears almost verbatim in the decompiled code hundreds of times, so once I "grok" this one example, I should have no problem with the rest of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of those things that dotPeek fails on but ILSpy handles nicely. What you're seeing is a compiler optimization of the `+=` operator. Rather than calculate the field location twice - once to fetch the value and again to store it - the compiler generates code that calculates the field offset one time then uses it for both parts of the operation.

The bit you're having trouble with (the unknown `^` operator) is most likely an attempt by dotPeek to show a dereference of the ref variable. Of course this isn't necessary in C# where we just use the name of the variable itself.

Just rewrite it as:

```
m_position += byteCount;
```

The compiler will decide whether or not it wants to add that particular optimization in.

Comment: Won’t this be `unchecked` by default? I should also note that I did try ILSpy and a couple others as well, but for the life of me I could not figure out how to generate code for anything but the reference assemblies using anything other than dotPeek.

Comment: @JacobStamm Generally yes, but you can wrap it: `checked { m_position += byteCount; }`.

Comment: Ooh I didn’t know that was possible. And you’re sure it’s braces, not parentheses?

Comment: @JacobStamm Braces to establish a checked scope around statements, parentheses for checked expressions.

Answer (score 2):

`long&` represents a reference type for a long and should be replaced with `ref long`.  It’s then assigning the address of the `m_position` field to the `local` variable (making `local` an alias for it), then checking for arithmetic overflow when adding the byte count to it.  Not entirely sure about the caret, in managed C++ it’s a [hat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/extensions/handle-to-object-operator-hat-cpp-component-extensions?view=msvc-170) to instruct for GC of object, so I suppose that’s what it’s doing.  When the arithmetic check completes successfully, the `m_position` field via `local` var is set to the current value plus `byteCount`.

```
ref long local = ref this.m_position;
long num = checked(local + (long)byteCount);
local = num;
```

Comment: I see, so the whole purpose is just to increment m_position by the byteCount. I think we can simplify by making it one line: `this.m_position = checked(this.m_position + (long)byteCount)`. Does that look right to you? Any possible difference in thread safety between our two versions?

Comment: Seems like it should be fine but then why the ref local in the first place?

Comment: There would be no ref local or num variables, just the field incrementing itself. As for why the IL (or maybe it’s dotPeek’s fault) considers it more efficient to have those two additional variables, I have no clue.